# add vector as row in data.table

Tags: r, data.table, rbind

I have a vector of length 6:

`[1] "Grand Total"       "4846157.05310486"  "799995.35"         "5646152.40310486"  "34658346091.75"    "-9600.78021642406"`

and a data.table with 17 objects and 6 variables

I can usually append the vector to the data table with rbind(table,list(vector))

but when i do it I get this message:

```
Error in rbindlist(l, use.names, fill, idcol) : 
  Item 2 has 1 columns, inconsistent with item 1 which has 6 columns. To fill missing columns use fill=TRUE.
```

I have been able to do this in the past with exactly the same scenario but with this it wont work

Comment: do you want `as.list(vector)` instead of `list(vector)`?

Comment: oh wow was that all i needed?? thanks so much

Answer (score 2):

solved by @MichaelChirico in the comments:

`rbind(table,as.list(vector))`

Comment: Note you may need to add `use.names=FALSE` to your rbind call dependent on version.